# Python Selenium find this element OR this element

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Wondering if there is a way to find the same element in 2 instances. I run into this problem where sometimes it finds the element and sometimes doesn't (Not a time issue)

Something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("Element xpath 1" or "Element xpath 2")
```

Comment: Note that `"Element xpath 1" or "Element xpath 2"` is evaluated to `"Element xpath 1"`, always.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve it would be to follow the [EAFP approach](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Element xpath 1")
except NoSuchElementException:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Element xpath 2")
```

Another approach would be to modify the expression and join two xpath expressions into a single one with "or" (a pipe character):

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//path1/to/element | //path2/to/element")
```